# Extract and compare multi line values

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I'm trying to extract data from a file that looks like this:

```
XLOC_000001 Schx    1   385 339.597 339.597 11.2848 -   OK
XLOC_000001 Schx    0   620 671.378 671.378 20.8907 -   OK
XLOC_000001 Schxdex 0   493 530.642 530.642 16.1373 -   OK
XLOC_000001 Schxdex 1   384 368.611 368.611 12.5572 -   OK
XLOC_000002 Schx    1   486 428.686 428.686 5.75646 -   OK
XLOC_000002 Schx    0   503 544.683 544.683 7.25738 -   OK
XLOC_000002 Schxdex 0   584 628.59  628.59  8.6694  -   OK
XLOC_000002 Schxdex 1   497 477.083 477.083 6.52573 -   OK
XLOC_000003 Schx    1   667 588.341 588.341 3.6527  -   OK
XLOC_000003 Schx    0   578 625.898 625.898 4.10985 -   OK
XLOC_000003 Schxdex 0   607 653.346 653.346 4.35889 -   OK
XLOC_000003 Schxdex 1   521 500.121 500.121 3.24867 -   OK
XLOC_000004 Schx    1   27  23.8159 23.8159 29.2102 -   OK
XLOC_000004 Schx    0   27  29.2374 29.2374 224.533 -   OK
```

The information in the first column shows a gene model, and the second shows a treatment group (either Schx or Schxdex). The 3rd column show the technical replicate for each treatment group (either 0 or 1). So, for the first gene model:

```
model    treatment    rep    value
XLOC_000001    Schx    1    11.2848
XLOC_000001    Schx    0    20.8907
XLOC_000001    Schxdex    0    16.1373
XLOC_000001    Schxdex    1    12.5572
```

I'm trying to make a comparison between data (the value I'm interested in is in column 7)

1) **within** each treatment group: `20.8907` Vs. `11.2848` and `16.1373` Vs. `12.5572`

and

2) **Between** each treatment group: `20.8907` Vs. `12.5572` and `11.2848` Vs. `16.1373`

I've written some code that allows me to perform a correlation test for the first comparison, but I can't work out how to do the same for the second. I'm filtering values (`$fpkm == 0` and `$fpkm > 5000`) and then transforming them. the test that I'm doing doesn't allow for missing data, so if a 0 or (>5000) is present in one comparison point then the whole model is removed:

```
my %data;
while (<$in>){
    chomp;
    next unless /^XLOC/;
    my @split = split;
    $data{$split[0]}{$split[1]}{$split[2]} = $split[6];
}

open my $out, '>', 'output.csv';

print $out "fpkm1,fpkm2\n";

my (%rep_count, $log_trans_fpkm, %filter, $fpkm);

for my $xloc (sort keys %data){
    for my $condition (keys $data{$xloc}){
        for my $replicate (sort keys $data{$xloc}{$condition}){
            $fpkm = $data{$xloc}{$condition}{$replicate};

            next if $fpkm == 0;
            $rep_count{$xloc}{$condition}++;

            $filter{$xloc}{$condition}{$replicate} = $fpkm if $replicate == 0 and $rep_count{$xloc}{$condition} == 1 and $condition eq 'Schx';
            $filter{$xloc}{$condition}{$replicate} = $fpkm if $replicate == 1 and $rep_count{$xloc}{$condition} == 2 and $condition eq 'Schx';
        }
        delete $filter{$xloc} if $fpkm == 0 or $fpkm > 5000;
    }
}

for my $id (sort keys %filter){
    for my $condition (keys $filter{$id}){
        for my $replicate (sort keys $filter{$id}{$condition}){
            my $fpkm = log2($filter{$id}{$condition}{$replicate});
            print $out "$fpkm," if $replicate == 0 and $condition eq 'Schx';
            print $out "$fpkm" if $replicate == 1 and $condition eq 'Schx';
        }
        print $out "\n";
    }
}
```

Would anyone be able to help me extract the data to make the second comparison?

Just to clarify the data I want to extract in this example is:

```
XLOC_000001 Schx    0   20.8907 
XLOC_000001 Schxdex 1   12.5572 
XLOC_000002 Schx    0   7.25738 
XLOC_000002 Schxdex 1   6.52573 
XLOC_000003 Schx    0   4.10985 
XLOC_000003 Schxdex 1   3.24867
```

To be formatted like this:

```
20.8907 12.5572
7.25738 6.52573
4.10985 3.24867
```

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify your question with an example, or write some mockup code.

Comment: log2() is not defined in your code example.

Comment: @xxfelixxx - sorry if i didn't put it in - it's just a small sub that takes the log2 fpkm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it is rather unclear what your criteria are for selecting a particular value for inclusion into your extract.  It *appears* that you want replicate 0 when treatment type is Schx, and replicate 1 when treatment type is Schxdex (from your example output).  If there is any other logic, it is non-obvious to me.

Modifying your script slightly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $input = 'input';
open my $in, "<", $input
  or die "Unable to open '$input' : $!";

my %data;
while (<$in>) {
    chomp;
    next unless /^XLOC/;
    my @split = split;
    #      model        treatment    replicate     value
    $data{ $split[0] }{ $split[1] }{ $split[2] } = $split[6];
}

open my $out, '>', 'output.csv';

print $out "fpkm1 fpkm2\n";

my ( %rep_count, $log_trans_fpkm, %filter, $fpkm );

for my $xloc ( sort keys %data ) {

    my ($schx, $schxdex);
    for my $treatment ( keys $data{$xloc} ) {
        if ('Schx' eq $treatment) {
            $schx = $data{$xloc}{$treatment}{ 0 };
        } elsif ('Schxdex' eq $treatment) {
            $schxdex = $data{$xloc}{$treatment}{ 1 };
        } else {
            die "Don't know what to do with treatment '$treatment'";
        }
    }
    my (@fpkm_ok) = grep { defined $_ and $_ != 0 and $_ <= 5000 } ($schx, $schxdex);
    if ( 2 == scalar @fpkm_ok ) {
        print $out join ' ', (@fpkm_ok, "\n");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
fpkm1 fpkm2
20.8907 12.5572
7.25738 6.52573
4.10985 3.24867
```

Comment: This exactly answers my question. I haven't used grep in perl much, but this is a really nice solution, so thanks!